# How to do unwind segue in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

I have a tab bar controller and two destination views, one of which is a table view (static cells) and the other is a view controller.
I can do a segue from one cell of the tableview to the yellow view controller but how can I do an unwind segue?
I know unwind segues require some code in the destination view controller but there are no destination view controllers in this case because the table view doesn't have a separate controller and neither does the tab bar controller

Comment: can you post your segue code and explain what do you mean by there is no controllers ?

Comment: I was trying it without code so I just put in a tab bar controller, wired it up to a table view and a view controller and then did a segue from one of the table view cells to the yellow view controller. It works but I can't get back from the yellow view controller to the table view. That's what I mean by no controllers - it's all been done in interface builder.

Comment: You can't do that without code. why don't you want to use code? You're gonna need to make class files for your view controllers eventually.

Comment: I realise that now Sam, and I have now made class files. But I've now got the problem of how to wire up the segues. I can segue to the yellow view controller from a cell but if I add another view controller my first segue disappears - I can only connect one segue. I'm wondering how to connect to multiple view controllers. I'll need to follow some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement Unwind Functionality, you have to firstly declare this function in your root view controller

```
@IBAction func performUnwindSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
```

then right click `Exit` menu of your root view controller in storyboard, that unwind function could be visible. Line it to your button in child view controller, then it should work.

A simple example could be found [here](https://github.com/Millionaryearl/Stack-Overflow/tree/master/UnWind)